# HTML/SVG: Referencing, using, and styling SVGs when SVG files in folder

Tags: html, css, svg

I downloaded the [Ikons](http://ikons.piotrkwiatkowski.co.uk/) set and unzipped them in the folder on my local machine where the HTML and css files are located.
So, the rough pathing is: C:...\TestSite\Index.html, C:...\TestSite\.css, C:...\TestSite\IKONS\SVG\

Here is my attempt at referencing this in the HTML:

```
<link href="file:///C:/.../TestSite/IKONS/SVG" rel="stylesheet">
```

When I open the developer tools in Firefox, it has generated a file with the following entries (lots of them, only putting a few examples):

```
300: file:///C:/.../TestSite/IKONS/SVG/
200: filename content-length last-modified file-type
201: alarm.svg 1499 Thu,%2008%20Nov%202018%2016:08:00%20GMT FILE 
201: alt.svg 874 Thu,%2008%20Nov%202018%2016:08:00%20GMT FILE 
201: android.svg 2107 Thu,%2008%20Nov%202018%2016:08:00%20GMT FILE 
201: apple.svg 1239 Thu,%2008%20Nov%202018%2016:08:00%20GMT FILE
```

I'm sorry for any obvious mistakes on my part, but could you please help me referencing/linking the SVG folder up with HTML so that I can start putting them on my site? Also, can you style/manipulate SVGs (such as color, size, etc.) with css or do you have to define the style in HTML?

If I am missing any information that would help, please let me know and I'll do my best to provide it.

Comment: Haven't used this particular package before but it looks like from what you're posting that it's not actually an icon font pack, but just a bunch of individual files you'd use like any other `<img>` or `background-image`

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, I've had experience using icon font packs before, but I'm also still new to css and html in general, so thanks for the pointer. I'll look at referencing them as imgs :)